# Getting property type and convert generic

Tags: c#, generics

i need convert a value of type generic.. but i need get the type of a property for convert... how i can do this ?

```
public static T ConvertToClass<T>(this Dictionary<string, string> model)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    foreach (var item in model)
    {                              
       type.GetProperty(item.Key).SetValue(obj, item.Value.DynamicType</*TYPE OF PROPERTY*/>());
    }
    return (T)obj;
}
public static T DynamicType<T>(this string value)
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: You should use Json.Net to do this. See here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207731/how-can-i-deserialize-json-to-a-simple-dictionarystring-string-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I recommend you stick to **@Aravol**'s answer,

If you really need the type of the property, there's a property (sorry for the redundancy) in `PropertyInfo` that might help you:

```
public static T ConvertToClass<T>(this Dictionary<string, object> model)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    foreach (var item in model)
    {                              
       PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty(item.Key);
       Type propertyType = property.PropertyType;
       property.SetValue(obj, item.Value.ConvertToType(propertyType));
    }
    return (T)obj;
}

public static object ConvertToType(this string value, Type t)
{
     return Convert.ChangeType(value, t);
}
```

---

Please note that I modified you `DynamicType` so it can receive a `Type` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you're converting from a dictionary, start by using a `Dictionary<string, object>` - everything derives from `object`, even structs.

this code will work simply by using [`SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194291(v=vs.110).aspx) because the method takes an `object` and thus won't care about the type until runtime. Give it the wrong type at runtime though, and it will throw an exception.

```
public static T ConvertToClass<T>(this Dictionary<string, object> model)
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    foreach (var item in model)
    {                              
       type.GetProperty(item.Key).SetValue(obj, item.Value);
    }
    return (T)obj;
}
```

Be wary of this code - by not using more complex overloads and try-catch statements, it will be very prone to runtime errors that don't make a lot of sense from the context of other methods - lots of serializations are able to use nonpublic setters, or are limited to fields. Read up on the overloads used by the Reflection methods!

Comment: Yes, show the exception on find a int property..i need convert the item.Value for type of property

Comment: In this case, you won't need to. Because everything and anything can be passed as an `object` the conversion doesn't happen until runtime. The alternative is unnecessary metacoding